# Laurent series for $|z-3|>3$

Tags: complex-analysis

How to expand $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ as laurent series on $D = \{ z \ |  \ |z-3|>3\}$. For $|z-3|< 3$, i know how to do it by considering $$f(z)= \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{1 +\frac{z-3}{3}} = \frac{1}{3} \cdot\left(1+\frac{z-3}{3}\right)^{-1}$$ but i dont know how to do for $|z-3|>3$.

A nice solution would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

$$
\frac1z = \frac{1}{3+(z-3)} = \frac{1}{z-3} \cdot \frac{1}{1+\frac{3}{z-3}}
$$